# Touch input from external monitor is recognized on the wrong screen

Tags: display, touchscreen

I have an external monitor that supports touch input. It's connected through HDMI and USB to my new MacBook Pro. When I touch the screen, the input is executed on the main display (so the internal one) instead of on the touchscreen itself (the external one).

I had a similar problem with my Windows laptop, but there is a setting for which screen the touch input is executed on. I couldn't find anything similar for Mac. Anybody got any tips?

Comment: What is your External monitor model ?

Comment: It's a no-name local brand. Under Mac OS it registers as "RTK FHD HDR".

Comment: I have the electriQ eiQ-15UHDPMT and have the same problem.